# Como gerar um nonce com o mod unique_id para a Content Security Police?

Tags: php, apache, segurança, http-headers

Estou tentando gerar um `nonce` para a [`CSP`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/?hl=pt-br), já habilitei o mod `unique_id` do Apache, e no `.htaccess` já está gerando corretamente.

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only style-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e';
```

No inspetor é possível ver que está funcionando, já que o report inclui o nonce:

> [Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
>   'nonce-XTDMkn8AAQPQHTAzOZ6cAAAAE'".
>   Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-1aqpLm6ug6vs34Tx89vHCLRgWo6n/fPxZgDY7CS2PT4='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

O problema é que quando uso a variável `$_SERVER ['UNIQUE_ID']` no HTML ele gera outra chave. O HTML possui elementos dinâmicos que alteram de acordo com variáveis do PHP:

```
$var = $var1 * $var2; // $var1 e $var2 sempre mudam

$myUniqId = $_SERVER ['UNIQUE_ID'];

<div class="star_bar" nonce="' . $myUniqId . '" style="width:' . $var . 'px;">
```

Olhando pelo fonte é possível ver que o unique id está sendo gerado no HTML, porém é diferente do que é gerado no `htaccess` (que aparece no report da mensagem acima).